# How to manually reclassify a contiguous region of misclassified pixels?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, digital-image-processing, land-classification

The attached image is the result of an image segmentation algorithm on high resolution imagery.  The smaller clusters of pixels represent trees and brush and the larger cluster of pixels (marked with a red arrow) is a misclassified farm field.  In ArcGIS 10.1 is there a way to select the misclassified pixels and reclassify them to 0 or NoData?

[image]

Comment: In graphics editing software like Photoshop you would use a ["flood fill"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) tool to recolor a contiguous region of same-colored pixels. I am not sure what the equivalent is in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible workflow using ModelBuilder and Spatial Analyst tools that works for me:

[image: ModelBuilder screenshot]

You supply the input raster, an XY coordinate for the location at which to sample for the region to be reclassified, and the new value of the classification.

The output is a new raster (it won't let you overwrite the input raster), but that can be overcome through Python scripting.

You could also implement this as a Python add-in to make it more interactive by creating a tool that responds to the mouse being clicked in the map and input those coordinates into the workflow.

Answer (score -1):

To do it "with" esri products you would need spatial analyst extension.
You would use the raster calculator to accomplish.
there are ways to do it with open source software.